# Steps to integrate flurry ad in android application

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics

I have to integrate the flurry ad in my android application. Can anybody provide the steps to integrate the flurry ad. I have gone through official sdk for flurry but not get any idea.   I have followed the link                                      [android: Flurry Ads Banner taking Full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392173/android-flurry-ads-banner-taking-full-screen)

I have used the code not get any results

```
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, getString(R.string.flurry_api_key));

    FlurryAds.fetchAd(this, "ANDROID_BANNER_TOP", mBanner,
            FlurryAdSize.BANNER_TOP);
```

Comment: did you add the framelayout required to display ads?

Comment: Yes. i have face the error like   06-07 16:36:20.778 17755-17835/: Ad server responded with the following error(s):
06-07 16:36:20.778 17755-17835/cE/FlurryAgent: Unknown placement type in test ads
06-07 16:36:20.840 17755-17769/W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.498ms
 E/ADS-FAILEDRECEIVE: ANDROID_BANNER_TOP

Comment: @Override
 public void spaceDidFailToReceiveAd(String arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Log.e("ADS-FAILEDRECEIVE", arg0);

 }  this callback get invoked

Answer (score 1):

> Prerequisites

Flurry Analytics requires a minimum Android API level 10.

Flurry Analytics uses the Android Advertising ID provided by Google Play Services and will check for and respect the user’s ad tracking preference.

> 1. Get your API Keys

Start by [creating an app](https://dev.flurry.com/secure/login.do). Once you create the app, you’ll receive a Flurry API Key, which you’ll need when using the SDK.

> 2. Download the Flurry Android SDK

There are currently two ways of getting the Flurry Android SDK into your application:

Install via jCenter (Recommended):
The Flurry SDK is available via jCenter. You can add it to your application by including the following in your build.gradle file:

```
// In your top level Gradle config file:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}


// In your main app's Gradle config file:
dependencies {
    compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.3.1'
    /*
     * Optional library to help in monetizing your app with ads.
     * If you include the ads library, you do not need to include
     * the analytics library as it is a transitive dependency.
     */
    // compile 'com.flurry.android:ads:6.3.1'

    //... other dependencies
}
```

Download .jar files from [Flurry Dev Portal](https://dev.flurry.com/uploadVersionSelectProject.do)
The downloaded archive should contain these files for use with Flurry Analytics:

- FlurryAnalytics_x.y.z.jar: The library containing Flurry’s analytic collection and reporting code (where x.y.x denotes the latest version of Flurry SDK).
- FlurryAds_x.y.z.jar: The optional library to incorporate Flurry’s ads into your application (where x.y.x denotes the latest version of Flurry SDK).
- ProjectApiKey.txt: This file contains the name of your project and your project’s API key.
- FlurryAndroidAnalyticsReadmevx.y.z.pdf: A PDF file with instructions (where x.y.x denotes the latest version of Flurry SDK).

> 3. Add the FlurryAnalytics_x.y.z.jar to your classpath¶

**Using Android Studio:**
If using Android Studio, you do not need to do anything further to include the Flurry SDK in your project, as long as you have installed the SDK through jCenter in your Gradle configuration.

However, if you prefer to use the downloaded .jar files, follow these procedures:

Add FlurryAnalytics-­5.x.x.jar to your project’s libs folder.
Navigate to File > Project Structure > Module > Dependencies. Click the ‘+’ button in the bottom of the ‘Project Structure’ popup to add dependencies. Select ‘File dependency’ and add libs/FlurryAnalytics­-5.x.x.jar.
Add Google Play Services library. If selectively compiling individual Google Play Service APIs, you should include the Google Analytics API.

**Using Eclipse**
Add FlurryAnalytics-­5.x.x.jar to your project’s libs folder. Right-click on each JAR file and select Build Path > Add to Build Path.
Add the Google Play Service library jar file.

**Configure your AndroidManifest.xml**
 - Have access to the Internet and allow the Flurry SDK to check state of the network connectivity.
 - Specify a versionName attribute in the manifest to have data reported under that version name.
 - Declare min version of that Android OS that the app supports. Flurry supports Android OS versions 10 and above.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.flurry.sample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <!--required permission-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <!--optional permission - highly recommended-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
    <!--optional permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">
        <!--your activities -->

    </application>
</manifest>
```

> 4. Add calls to init, onStartSession and onEndSession

Follow these steps, adding these calls:

1. If you are shipping an app, insert a call to FlurryAgent.init(Context, String) in your Application class, passing it a reference to your application Context and your project’s API key:

//If you are shipping an app, extend the Application class if you are not already doing so:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        new FlurryAgent.Builder()
            .withLogEnabled(false)
            .build(this, FLURRY_API_KEY);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you may call init() just before onStartSession(). It is safe to call init() more than once, provided that you use the same API key throughout the application. You may use any type of Context you wish.

2. If you are writing an app and the minimum target is Ice Cream Sandwich or above (minSdkVersion is set to API level 14 or greater), session handling is completely automatic, and you may skip steps 3 and 4. If you are instrumenting another type of Context, such as a Service, or your minimum target is Gingerbread, proceed with steps 3 or 4.
3. Insert a call to FlurryAgent.onStartSession(Context) in the Activity’s onStart() method, passing it a reference to a Context object (such as an Activity or Service). If you are targeting Gingerbread, Flurry recommends using the onStart() method of each Activity in your app, and passing the Activity itself as the Context object. For services (or other Contexts), use the Service or the relevant Context as the Context object. Do not pass in the global Application context.
4. Insert a call to FlurryAgent.onEndSession(Context) in the Activity’s onStop() method, when a session is complete. If you are targeting Gingerbread, we recommend using the onStop method of each Activity in your app. For services (or other Contexts), ensure that onStop is called in each instrumented Service. Make sure to match up a call to onEndSession for each call of onStartSession, passing in the same Context object that was used to call onStartSession. Do not pass in the global Application context.

As long as there is any Context that has called onStartSession() but not onEndSession(), the session will be continued. Also, if a new Context calls onStartSession() within 10 seconds of the last Context calling onEndSession(), then the session will be resumed, instead of a new session being created. Session length, usage frequency, events and errors will continue to be tracked as part of the same session. This ensures that as a user transitions from one Activity to another in your app that they will not have a separate session tracked for each Activity, but will have a single session that spans many activities. If you want to track Activity usage, Flurry recommends using logEvent(), as described in the Custom Events section.

If you wish to change the window during which a session can be resumed, call FlurryAgent.setContinueSessionMillis(long milliseconds) before the call to FlurryAgent.init().

The Flurry SDK automatically transfers the data captured during the session once the SDK determines the session completed. In case the device is not connected, the data is saved on the device and transferred once the device is connected again. The SDK manages the entire process. Currently, there is no way for the app to schedule the data transfer.

> You’re done! That’s all you need to do to begin receiving basic metric
>   data.

Comment: is the same process to integrate flurry ad....because i need to integrate flurry ad..

Comment: can you provide steps to integrate flurry ad

Comment: Yes it's the prerequisite to add flurry ads.

Comment: “Ad server responded but sent no ad units” in Flurry in android   i have faced the error like this...how to get ride this...is there any problem in creating ads or problem with the code i have done

Comment: can you provide any samples

Comment: @shriduttkothari can u please tell me flurry ad unit id where we use in coding ??

Comment: @shriduttkothari  .build(this, FLURRY_API_KEY);  here u use API_KEY .. which is this api key?

Comment: @GB_Bhayaniツ yes i know, FLURRY_API_KEY is the constant i created, i can not post it's value in the answer.